# PowerShell Copy-Item gives error in Octopus

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I try to copy a DLL file from my computer to another and register it:

```
net use \\RemoteIp\C$\Dev 'pass'/USER:'user'
```

`copy-item "D:\test.dll" -Destination "\\RemoteIp\c$\Dev";`

```
regsvr32 "\\RemoteIp\C$\Dev\test.dll"
```

The problem that I have is that when I try to run this script from Octopus I receive this error :

> Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'D:\test.dll' because it does 
>   not exist.
>   At C:\Octopus\Work\20160606100457-74\Script.ps1:3 char:10
>   + copy-item <<<<  "D:\test.dll" -Destination "\RemoteIp\c$\Dev";
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\test.dll 
>      :String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyI 
>      temCommand
>   The remote script failed with exit code 1

If I try to run these lines of code in PowerShell it works properly.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: Well either the DLL is not yet created when the scripts is run or the path is not accessible from where the script is run.

Comment: For example: Is D: a mapped drive that is not accessible to the user running Octopus?

Comment: Hello, actually @marsze was right, I did not access the dll in a proper way, so the octopus did not know from where to take it. But here I have another problem. It seems that Octopus is stuck at the regvsr32 command. It copied my dll properly but it seems that he can not register it. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: I am pretty sure you need admin rights for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this was my fault. When you are running a script in Octopus that is meant to run on the  Deployment target: [image: 1]]

you have to define your local pc with the ip address. For example, in my case I had to write the address "D:\test.dll" like this : "\192.168.00.00\D$\test.dll" .

For the `regsvr32` problem, I added a bat file on the server that runs the regsvr32 instruction and I just call that file and it does the rest.

Hopefully that helps others :)